# How can I modify the autocompletion output in Sublime Text?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

The question is in the title,

I'd like for example to have `<img src="" alt=""/>` instead of just `<img src="">`

Do you know where is the file that is managing this part of my favorite editor?

Comment: You **SHOULD** put `alt` attribute in your `img` tag

Comment: @Blag have you even understood my question ?

Comment: *put the brain in the other way* oh~~ my bad... (2m I send you the answer you need ;) )

Answer (score 0):

How to use your own :

https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide/extensibility/snippets.html

A img basic snippet :

https://github.com/cozuya/custom-sublime-snippets/blob/master/img.sublime-snippet

---

maybe a completion is better than a snippet in fact :

https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide/extensibility/completions.html

---

if you want to change it deep inside ST :

`Sublime Text 2/Pristine Packages/HTML.sublime-package/html_completions.py`

Comment: Pristine Packages is probably a packages.. still I can't find it with Package Controle browser and I'm not sure I want to install it neither.
Through all I read on docs.sublimtext if I get it right, the autocompletion is done via json files however I don't find which fill I shall edit...

Comment: http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=7196#p30726 for the completion file ; and pristine seem to be the default package with everything (so not display in the package browser, you have to use a file browser)